# Android-Universal-Image-Loader example with grid view

Tags: android, gridview

Can you please send me full code tell me how we can use the Android-Universal-Image-Loader library in eclipse with gridview.

Thank you,

Comment: Check out my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android/24134425#24134425

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this link [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Download the Library using the link and import it to eclipse.
Also import the sample app and try using it,It worked for me.

Comment: but @Ritesh the sample app are using for android studio not for eclipse